# White screen in 4.7.12

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, smarty

I note with the 4.7.12 version of the difficulties of implementation, particularly with queries that only lead to blank pages.
Track errors in apache located abnormalities in smarty.
I returned to version 4.6.22 LTS that does not pose this problem.

Installation on a dedicated server ubuntu 14.04, apche 2.2 mysql 5.5.52 php5 wordpress 4.6

cordially

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It would be helpful if you could be more specific about the problems that you are experiencing.  Could you say what you were doing that led to a blank page?

Comment: I tried importing contacts from a CSV file. (About 650ko)

Comment: Between step 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your php5 version, that would be the most likely cause (i.e if it's less than 5.4).

But if the problem is seen in an apache error file and it's in the smarty file, then just give us the error and it should be clearer.

If you only updated the code files and didn't clear caches afterwards and run db updates, then you'll definitely want to do that, as per the documentation.

Comment: I went to a new server installation.
Ubuntu 16.04 Apache 2.2 PHP MySQL 5.6 Wordpress 4.6 and 7.01 CiviCRM 7.12. It is in this context that I noticed abnormalities with smarty to the line 447 according to the apache log.

I am now back has lts version of all software particularly with CiviCRM 4.6.22 I see no malfunctions with this set.

Comment: Correction PHP 7.01

Comment: PHP 7 isn't fully supported by CiviCRM yet - see my answer for details.

Comment: We could spend less time speculating if you provide the actual errors you are seeing in Apache.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this may be due to your PHP version.  CiviCRM doesn't fully support PHP 7 yet.

See: [CiviCRM PHP Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements)

Comment: Actually 4.7.12 supports PHP7. The issue is marked as fix for that version.
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789

Comment: Not according to the wiki (see my link above).  Perhaps the wiki needs to be updated?